# How to attack these types of questions: $f(f(x) - 1) = 1 + x^{16}$, solve for $f(2)$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Given a function $f(x)$ such that,

$f(f(x)-1) = 1 + x^{16}$

Solve for $f(2)$.

**Attempt:**
 I have tried to solve the problem by letting different values for x such as $x = 0, 1, 2,..$ to make the given function $f(f(0)-1) = 1, f(f(1)-1) = 2, f(f(2)-1) = 1 + 2^{16}$ but I am stuck and it seems my attempt is going nowhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - 1$.  Then $$f(f(x) - 1) - 1 = x^{16},$$ or $$g(g(x)) = x^{16}.$$  Intuitively, one such solution to this functional equation is $g(x) = x^4$, since then $g(g(x)) = (x^4)^4 = x^{16}$.  Then we would have $f(x) = x^4 + 1$, and $f(2) = 17$.  The only remaining issue is whether this solution is unique, which I leave as an exercise for the reader.